# How to make div only showing first 50 characters css

Tags: html, css, styling

I am trying to make my card Option Clause only showing first 100 characters but I am having issues with the css that I added these 3 line of code did not work for me :

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Here is my code base :

```
<div className="LoanReviewCard">
  <p className="subHeader-text">BASICS</p>
  <p className="header-text">
    {currentLoanRequest.loanProposalDetails.purpose}
  </p>
  ...
  <p className="review-text">
    <span className="bold">Optional Clause:</span>{" "}
    {currentLoanRequest.loanProposalDetails.addLoanClause.length > 0 ? (
      currentLoanRequest.loanProposalDetails.addLoanClause
    ) : "None"}
  </p>
</div>
```

css file :

```
.review-text {
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    .bold {
        font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    font-size: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: initial;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

issues line word too long, just want to show first 50 characters

[image]

Comment: Why it has to be **50** characters? Isn't it better to cap it for something like *4 lines*?

Comment: Do you still need the page to actually have the full text? If not i suggest manipulating the text length before its displayed instead of using css to hide it

Comment: _"css file :"_ - that would be invalid CSS - unless you actually meant to say that this was SASS or LESS or something like that?

Comment: @CBroe css file i mean like `styles.scss` my bad

Comment: @HaoWu how to make it like only 4 lines?

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;` is not going to have any effect, if you overwrite it with `white-space: initial;` three lines later within the same rule. And I doubt keeping in `word-break: break-word;` makes much sense either, if you _don't_ want the content to break into multiple lines.

Comment: _"how to make it like only 4 lines?"_ - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/

Answer (score 2):

```js
var string = $('.str').text();
var str50 = string.substr(0,50) 
$('.str').html(str50+'...'+'<a class="readmore" href="#">readmore</a>');
$('.str').attr('data-text',string);

$('.readmore').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().html($(this).parent().attr('data-text'))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='str'>
How To Display 1st 50 characters Of Text by using , html, css, javascript, jquery . and after 50 charecters create link for show the total text
</div>
```

Comment: Can you edit it with react?